# xpath Error while searching attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Hello I would like to extract with xpath all items with the name="Frequency" which contains a certain value but it doesn't give me anything. What Am I doing wrong?

XML File:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <title>PT2400</title>
        <ElectricSpecifications>
           <item name="Frequency">2310 - 2485 MHz (WLAN, BLUETOOTH, ZIGBEE</item>
        </ElectricSpecifications>
    </product>
</products>


foreach ($xpath->query("//product/ElectricSpecifications[@item='Frequency'][contains(., ' $value')]") as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`item` is not an attribute of `ElectricSpecifications`, but its child node, so instead of

```
[@item='Frequency']
```

syntax, try

```
item[@name='Frequency']
```

And so complete XPath should be like

```
//product/ElectricSpecifications/item[@name='Frequency' and contains(., ' $value')]
```